# How to get type hints to display?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

I have seen youtubers and such working on Rust in VSC with rust-analyzer plug-in where they get the optional type annotations displayed, even if it isn't necessarily written in the code. It's like I type `foo(a,b)` in the editor and it automagically displays `foo(a: A, b: B)` where the `:A` and `:B` are in faint grey possibly not even written in the file, just visual hint? It's nice and I can't figure out whether this is a feature of VSC or rust-analyzer? My rust-analyzer has the two settings Parameter Hints and TypeHints both set to enabled.

Comment: Does it show when you create a function that has more than one parameter?

Comment: Are you sure that language server is installed. Rust-analyzer suggests to install it after being itself installed using a popup which really easy to miss.

Comment: Both comments turned out to be useful! Fwiw I think there was a conflict between rust-analyzer and the VSC rust-lang plugin, causing some features to not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove type annotation help when using rust-analyzer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69909997/how-can-i-remove-type-annotation-help-when-using-rust-analyzer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for `parameter hints` in this case. The function for which you want to display hints also needs to have more than one parameter.

Make sure that the setting is enabled:

**Settings (UI)**

```
Inlay hints: Parameter hints
```

**Settings (JSON)**

```json
"rust-analyzer.inlayHints.parameterHints": true
```

You should then end up with something akin to the following:

```rust
fn add(x: u32, y: u32) -> u32 {
    x + y    
}

fn main() {
    let result = add(x: 4, y: 2);
}
```

---

Make sure that only `rust-analyzer` is enabled as it can conflict with `rls`. A warning [was added](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/issues/6463) which mentions the following if both are enabled:

```
You have both rust-analyzer (matklad.rust-analyzer) and Rust (rust-lang.rust)
plugins enabled. These are known to conflict and cause various functions of
both plugins to not work correctly. You should disable one of them.
```

Comment: Just to check, are you using `matklad.rust-analyzer` or `rust-lang.rust` VSC extension? It's confusing because the latter says "powered by Rust Analyzer" and it seems to have a higher install count. Looks like the extension reviews are better for `matklad.rust-analyzer`

Comment: @JSStuball it indeed is confusing. I _only_ have [`rust-analyzer`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matklad.rust-analyzer) installed as an extension. It is part of the `rls-2.0` effort. Perhaps there is a conflict? The `rust-lang.rust` extension mentions that it is able to install either.

Comment: Alright cheers, everything appears to be working fine with only `rust-analyzer` enabled so I'll roll with it for now.

Comment: @JSStuball great! I've added some more information to my answer that mentions the possible conflict between these two.

Answer (score 4):

rust-analyzer shows inlay hints for:

- Types of local variables
- Names of function arguments
- Types of chained expressions

You can toggle inlay hints by adding this to your `settings.json`:

```
{
  "rust-analyzer.inlayHints.enable": true
}
```

Or you can search "rust inlay" in your VSCode preferences.