# How can I remove type annotation help when using rust-analyzer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

For VS Code, I use `rust-analyzer` to handle syntax highlighting and flychecking.

How do I remove the inlay type and parameter annotations in grey below?

[image]

Comment: parameter hints and type hints

Comment: I wish rust analyzer turned off inlay annotations by default. While they're great for people who want them, using them by default adds unnecessary noise to the language. An important benefit of strong type inference like Rust's is that you don't have to clutter the code with annotations. While the code is technically not cluttered here (the annotations are just added by the IDE), _visually_ the result is as if they are.

Comment: While I agree about the default setting, I personally favor the Microsoft style guide which says that all declarations should be explicitly type annotated, except for calls to a constructor. My main problem with `rust-analyzer` was the mess that the "inlays" made to my line lengths, which is normally strictly enforced by my auto formatter. I might be in the minority about explicit type annotations though.

Comment: More like type annotation "help" amirite?

Comment: "I personally favor the Microsoft style guide which says that all declarations should be explicitly type annotated" since when there is a microsoft style for Rust ? also, that simply is impossible in Rust and is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: @user4815162342 An important benefit of strong type inference like Rust's is that *you* don't have to clutter the code with annotations. I still want to see the inferred type of an expression (especially when I'm not sure what type a function returns), I just don't want to have to type it out myself.

Comment: @BallpointBen Oh, it's definitely useful to be able to see the result of type inference, and that's typically available by hovering over the variable. I'm only taking about showing the result of _all_ type inferences and cluttering the declaration of every variable. That's fine for people who opt in, but it's a bad default because it adds unnecessary text and makes the whole language appear cluttered and weird.

Comment: Here's how you'd keep the hint but remove the bright blue background: [Disable background color for types in BSCode while using Rust](/q/73020238/2189130)

Comment: very strongly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68698269/how-can-i-toggle-inlay-hints-in-vs-code

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**New Answer for VS Code:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/72338341/9363973

If you're not using VS Code you'll need to manually edit the JSON config file of your rust-analyzer install ([helpful link to the documentation](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#configuration)). Basically

1. Open the JSON config file in your favourite text editor
2. Add a new property to the root of the JSON object like so:

```json
{
    "inlayHints": {
        "typeHints": false,
        "parameterHints": false
    },
    // further configuration
}
```

---

**Old answer for VS Code:**

In Visual Studio Code you can easily do this.

1. Open the settings page (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)
2. Search for "rust-analyzer inlay"
3. Uncheck things you don't want

   - In your case that would be "Parameter Hints" and "Type Hints"

Answer (score 94):

**Update Sept 2022**.

They now use VSCode [builtin inlay function from 1.67](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_toggle-inlay-hints)

I setup mine as follow:

```json
{
  "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "offUnlessPressed"
}
```

Then you can toggle them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> pressed.

---

**Old Answer**

There is now a togglable command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) : `Rust Analyzer: Toggle inlay hints`

Comment: Ctrl+Alt seems to also activate the menu, though, which is obnoxious.

Comment: To prevent activating the menu, make sure to press Alt first, and Ctrl second.