# Remove blue box text on vscode rust (Im using rust-analyzer)

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, settings

So I keep getting this blue box on rust, and it is getting really annoying, how can I get rid of it?

[Click to view my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFpY7.png)

Comment: These are called *inlay hints*. I don't know vscode, but I guess that if you look for such an option in the settings, then you could disable it.

Comment: Those are type and parameter hints. You can disable them by following the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69909997/can-i-remove-type-annotation-help-from-rust-analyzer

Comment: Though I usually see them less pronounced, I wonder if your theme is causing them to be highlighted in bright blue.