# Configure Rust Analyzer to disable Inlay Hints when used in Eclipse IDE with Corrosion

Tags: eclipse, rust, rust-language-server, inlay-hints

I'm using the latest Eclipse IDE (2023-03) with Corrosion, and the Rust Analyzer (1.69.0). But the inlay hints clutter up the code a lot, while these hints provide no new information. I would very much like to turn off inlay hints entirely.

According to the [documentation](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#configuration), *"some clients such as [VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69909997/how-can-i-remove-type-annotation-help-when-using-rust-analyzer) and COC plugin in Vim"*, but for other editors (like Eclipse) *"the initial configuration is specified as a value of the* `initializationOptions` *field of the* `InitializeParams` *message, in the LSP protocol."*

In Eclipse, the configuration screen (Windows -> Preferences -> Rust) allows for installing and configuring the Rust Analyzer, by means of an empty field called `LS Configuration`. Presumably I need to point to a configuration file which holds the JSON-formatted message that is to be sent over the LSP protocol ?

I've created this `settings.json` file with the following content:

```
{
  "inlayHints" : {
    "chainingHints" : { "enable" : false },
    "parameterHints" : { "enable" : false }
  }
}
```

I tried pointing Eclipse to the file, restart Eclipse, adding another level `"rust-analyzer"` before `"inlayHints"`, but nothing works.
And Rust Analyzer currently seems to be [lacking documentation](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/documentation-for-rust-analyzer-settings/49762), although some third parties [have published instructions](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/master/docs/development/languages/rust/editors.md) for other IDE's.

How can I change the default configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable inlay hints for the Rust Analyzer in Eclipse:

1.) Create some `settings.json` file:

```
{
  "inlayHints" : {
    "typeHints" : { "enable" : false },
    "chainingHints" : { "enable" : false }, 
    "parameterHints" : { "enable" : false },  
    "closingBraceHints" : { "enable" : false }
  }
}
```

2.) Make sure the file is readable by the same user account that runs Eclipse.

3.) Open Eclipse.

4.) On the menu bar, open Window -> Preferences, go to the tab Rust.

5.) Click on the folder icon of the field "LS Configuration"

6.) Choose the `settings.json` file and click "Apply and Close"

7.) Restart Eclipse