# Why is vscode inserting a `: String` in my for loop?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

As you can see in the following picture, vscode is inserting that pink highlighted `: String` in the for loop. There is no actual text there, as if I move the cursor, it just skips over it, so it's just visual. What is vscode telling me to do with it? there's no suggestion when I hover over it.

[image]

Comment: Is it inserting the type-name into the _saved_ Rust source file, or is it "virtual text" that's added in the code editor window but not actually part of the saved file?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66174400/how-to-get-type-hints-to-display

Comment: @Dai It's just virtual text. If I open the source file in anoter text-editor, there is no type-name. What's also weird, is that if I then type in `: String` like it shows, it throws a syntax error, so it isn't even correct, so I'm not sure what the point of it is.

Comment: @Dai, RE: the parameter hints, I disabled both parameter hints settings for the rust-analyzer extension, and it only got rid of the colon, but left the type-name.

Comment: Ah I found it. It was the "type-hints" option.

Comment: @Kalcifer "so I'm not sure what the point of it is" - it is very useful when your program is larger than a hello world.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode is simply telling you the type of `argument`. The rust analyzer module puts these in places where the type is inferred to let you know what type the variable actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling `rust-analyzer.inlayHints.typeHints.enable` removes type hints.